# How do you use character variables in Bash for if statements?

Tags: bash

For example I have something written like this

```
read -p "Enter a character: " variable
if [ $variable -eq 'A' ];
```

I'm getting an error that says integer expression expected, but I don't want to use an integer variable I want to use a character?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on RHEL 6.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rN1 -p "Enter a character: " variable; echo>&2
if [ "$variable" = 'A' ]; then
  echo Capital A
else
  echo something else
fi
```

Though if you're going to compare against several characters, you may want to use a `case` construct instead:

```
case "$variable" in
  (A)   echo Capital A;;
  (b)   echo Lower case B;;
  ('\') echo Backslash;;
  (*)   echo something else;;
esac
```

Comment: Does the == work specifically for character variables? I think I've tried that with integer variables and the program would not work unless I used -eq.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/bash-equality-operators-eq#:~:text=%3D%3D%20is%20a%20bash%2Dspecific,a%20numeric%20comparison%20of%20course.

== is a bash-specific alias for = and it performs a string (lexical) comparison instead of a numeric comparison. eq being a numeric comparison of course.